# Using import java.util.Random; nextInt and user input

Tags: java, random

I am fairly new to java so this will probably seem like a basic question. I am trying to use the random java.util and nextInt to create a random number in a range specified by user input and then cast it as a character, to then be stored in an array;

```
gridCells[x][y] = (char)(r.nextInt(numberOfRegions) + 'a');
```

However, because I want nextInt to use user Input, and although im controlling the range of values, im guessing the error is caused because nextInt thinks numberOfRegions could be 0?

```
// Map Class
import java.util.Random;

public class map
{
    // number of grid regions 
    private int numberOfRegions; 
    private boolean correctRegions = false 

    // grid constants
    private int xCord = 13; // 13 so the -1 makes 12 for a 12x12 grid
    private int yCord = 13; 

    // initiate grid
    private int[][] gridCells = new int[xCord][yCord];

    Random r = new Random();

    map() { }

    // ask for number of regions
    public void regions()
    {
        keyboard qwerty = new keyboard(); // keyboard class
        while(correctRegions = false)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter the number of regions: ");
            numberOfRegions = qwerty.readInt();
            if(numberOfRegions < 2) // nothing less then 2 accepted
            {
                correctRegions = false;
            }
            else if(numberOfRegions > 4) // nothing greater then 4 accepted
            {
                correctRegions = false;
            }
            else
            {
                correctRegions = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // fills the grid with regions
    public void populateGrid()
    {
        for(int x =0; x<gridCells[x].length-1; x++) // -1 to avoid outofboundsexception error 
        {
            for(int y =0; y<gridCells[y].length-1; y++)
            {
                gridCells[x][y] = (char)(r.nextInt(numberOfRegions) + 'a');    
            }
        }
    }

    public void showGrid()
    {
        for(int x=0;x<gridCells[x].length-1; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<gridCells[x].length-1; y++)
            {
                System.out.print(gridCells[x][y] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: private boolean correctRegions = false;`
has a extra ` mark and won't compile...

Comment: This belongs more to codereview.stackexchange than here...

Comment: For some reason the error didn't show (must have been when I added the code into the post) it's the illegalargumentexception n must be positive error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void populateGrid()
{
    for(int x =0; x<gridCells[x].length-1; x++) // -1 to avoid outofboundsexception error 
    {
        for(int y =0; y<gridCells[y].length-1; y++)
        {
            gridCells[x][y] = (char)(r.nextInt(numberOfRegions) + 'a'); 
        }
    }
}
```

This is bogus, either you do `index < array.length` or `index <= array.length-1`.

`index < array.length-1` is most likely not what you intended.

Also, if you get compilation errors, it is maybe because you did not initialize numberOfRegions. Normally, thats not an error but a warning, but maybe your compiler is set to issue an error in this case. Try

```
private int numberOfRegions = 0;
```

Comment: I tried assigning numberOfRegions but then when it came to running my program it bypassed the while loop and didn't ask for user input. Is this because I messed up the ==?

Comment: @user3036238 yes that's because of the operator, if you change the `=` to `==` your while loop won't be skipped.

Comment: Thank you ill change it out after my lecture and ill get back to you to. Sorry for the basic question, feel bad for missing the == haha

Comment: Yep works now having assigned numberOfRegions. Also changed the index < array.lenth -1 as well thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

you have to know how the java.util.random works.

```
Random r = new Random();

int number = r.nextInt(numberOfRegions);
```

this will produce an integer from zero (0) to ur numberRegions.
to exclude zero from ur possible range of random number generated, do something like this

```
int number = 1 + r.nextInt(numberOfRegions);
```

with this, the minimum number that can be generated is 1

```
int number = 2 + r.nextInt(numberOfRegions);
```

with this, the minimum number that can be generated is 2

```
...and so on
```

Comment: Okay thank you ill try that out too after my lecture.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found something:

Your `while` condition is an assignment:

```
while(correctRegions = false)
```

You should write:

```
while(correctRegions == false) // == is a boolean operator, = is an assignment
```

Comment: Thank you I'm not really used to java I started with pascal I forget the == equality often